# How can I edit this code so that it only changes the Top Menu bar on my homepage when a user is logged in without changing the Main Menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using OceanWP theme to create my site.

I have two different menus on my homepage, I have a top menu and I also have a main menu. http://prntscr.com/pofn5r

I would like for the top menu to display different options for users who are logged in and users who are logged out.

I have used the following code which I placed in the functions.php file. I have also created two different menus for logged in and logged out users:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged_in';
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = 'logged_out';
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

It seems to work in terms of showing different menus for users which are logged in and users which are logged out but the problem is that it also changes the main menu as well as the top menu.

prntscr.com/podv5e

I wanted the main menu to remain the same and just have the top menu change.

I was wandering whether there was a way I could adjust the code so that it would only apply to the top menu and not the main menu?

Comment: Seems like the same code and exact question from a few years ago: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208893/two-different-menus-for-two-different-locations

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    echo "Here you put HTML code when logged in";
} else { 
    echo "Here you put HTML code when logged out"
} 
}
```

since echo will work like it is writted directly into HTML

Comment: The code is not the OP's but borrowed from an example. He has no idea how to respond to your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Teemo, thank you for this. Actually the code I am using is working ok but the issue I am having is that the main menu, which is underneath the top menu, is also mirroring the top menu. I only wanted the top menu to change based on whether user is logged in/out but wanted the main menu to remain the same either way: prntscr.com/pogjjd . Any idea how I can edit the code so that only the top menu changes and the main menu is not affected?

Comment: Well you in fact use only HTML code of the top menu, not whole menu. Also some more information with your own code would help.

Comment: Ahh I see. I am a bit of a newbie to this. I am not sure where to find the HTML for the top menu. Here is what I can see in firefox: http://prntscr.com/pohp3a . Would it be any of these?

The code I am using was given to me from another user to another question I asked previously. What information would you need about the code?

Comment: I wanted to know what kind of changes does the php code do to HTML of the top menu. From what it seems, the top menu and main menu are connected somehow and you need to make them seperate. It can be maybe some variable, which reffers to top menu and main menu at the same time.The change your code then affect this variable, which affects both top and main menu. But I also might be wrong and this issue is truly a mystery :/